# 500 internal error Laravel, getting images through websocket daemon

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, phpwebsocket

I have a chat daemon running on Laravel project.

If I try to send to the client from a server a string, which contains HTML, I get 500 error (not 404, the file exists. Here is a example of a string

```
<img src="{{ asset('path/to/img.png') }}">
```

Here is the error I got in PHP logs:

> request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. use 'limitinternalrecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. use 'loglevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Again: If I echo this string in client (view), it will be ok, but if I get it like a message (to client from server) I get an error.

Comment: What websocket code are you using? add some code

Comment: I'm using a package from github, this is websocket for laravel framework. There are a couple of vendor classes, but I'll share with you my controllers methods.

Comment: This is baseChatController method

/**
     * Requests from clients handler
     * $query is a JSON, contains query type (cmd type or msg) and msg text(or cmd)
     *
     */
    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $query) {
        $query = json_decode($query);

        if($query->type == 'cmd'){
            $this->command($from, $query->msg);
        }

    }

Comment: And here is extending class method, which render blade to the client

 public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
   {
       parent::onOpen($conn); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
      parent::sendMessage($conn, view('onboardchat._first_step', ['name' => 'Steven'])->render());
   }

Comment: There are dozens of websockets libraries, You did not tell me which one & you can edit your question to add the code with formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The function asset() returned a url like this:

```
http://localhost/path/to/img.png
```

The problem was in missing port. I edited my .env file and changed the base url

from

```
http://localhost
```

to

```
http://localhost:8000
```